# 2006 Matrix air conditioning fan changes speeds when set at high, but air flow seems the same?

Tags: ac

The fan set at high sounds like it fluxuates in speed, but the air  flow seems to be the same? Have had checked at dealer. They replaced fan, but still have the problem! They do not know what is wrong. About 4 months ago the alternator went out and was replaced, but the fan problem was later than that. Noticed the digital clock on rare occasion goes out for a second or two. Not sure if that is important in the diagnosis?

Comment: are you using the a/c when this happens? any correlation with something like the cooling fans coming on? or does it do this regardless?

Comment: Try checking if the cabin air filter is dirty. Dirty cabin air filter means less airflow and more strain on the blower.